# In Adf I want to make a column 'test' that has a different value for every month value in the 'date' column

Tags: azure, where-clause, azure-data-factory

I have a column full with dates. Now I want to make a second column 'test' that is based on this column. Whenever the month changes in the 'date' column I want the number in the 'test' column to be different. So for example, I want the number to be 10 if the month is June and 14 if the month is February .... Can I do this with the 'derived column' and a where clause or something?

At the moment I am trying to do this as follows:
[image]

Comment: can you add what you tried some images? and sample input output?

Comment: you can try case statement `case(month($$)==6,10,case(month(datetime)==7,15,case(month(datetime)==10,20)))
` like this

Answer (score 0):

Provided you’re happy with the number being the numerical version of the month (and not random), you can use the following code in a Derived Column:

```
month(yourDateTime)
```

EDIT: Given the update in requirements, the `case()` function may be better suited given it allows multiple if statements

```
case(month(yourDateTime) == 6, 10, month(yourDateTime) == 2, 14, ...)
```